# reduce size of default Quartz / plot object

Tags: r

I have a laptop with low screen resolution. As a consequence, when I give a plot command in `R` the `Quartz` plot object runs off the screen.

Is it possible to change set some option -- preferably in my `.Rprofile`  -- that will reduce the size of the default plot output when using interactive `R`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
?quartz
quartz.options(width=4, height=4)
```

(The default values are 7 and 7 which can eaisly be obtained by typing just:

```
quartz.options()[c("width", "height")]  # .)
```

Comment: Wonderful -- i wish i'd asked earlier!